# How to call a function from Linq statement without a return value?

Tags: c#, linq

I've written a LINQ statement that matches a list of enum names to any entries that are present in a dictionary.  I then want to call a function and pass the matched string to it.  I have this and it works but it smells a bit, particularly having to return a string from my function.

```
var pas = Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums))                          
               .Select(x => { return DoSomething(x); }).ToList();
```

And `DoSomething` look like:

```
private string DoSomething(string name)
{
    // do stuff
    return name;  
}
```

Can it be rewritten so that I can make the function void?

Comment: don't use `.Select`.

Comment: `Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums)).ToList().Foreach'

Comment: using linq no, however if you just want to execute a function you can call ForEach on either a list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx or Parallel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, the whole concept of the iterators is returning a new iterator with chained expressions in the tree. Your functions have to return a value, that will be the value transformed to the new iterator. If you want to use a void function, e.g. terminate the stream, use `ForEach`

Comment: I Agree with @MikeT. **Select** is really for transforming the data. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks - OK , is the performance of the ForEach better than what I am currently doing with Select'?

Comment: If you do `ForEach` second time with another action, then - no. Because `Select` will just chain a new expression, but `ForEach` will enumerate the iterator second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is for Selecting data, as void has no data then you can't use it.

but there are 2 methods designed for calling functions on a list of values

From List

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums)).ToList().ForEach(DoSomething)
```

from Parallel

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums)), DoSomething)
```

the second will use multiple thread to execute them asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

try [List.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums)).ToList().ForEach(x => DoSomething(x));
```

Comment: thanks - I have this:  Enum.GetNames(typeof(ProductAttributeList)).ToList().ForEach(SetAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways forward. If you insist on putting it in the `Select`, you could do this:

```
var pas = Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums))
              .Select(x => { 
                   DoSomething(x);
                   return x;
              }).ToList();
```

But the following would be a cleaner approach:

```
var pas = Enum.GetNames(typeof(enums)).ToList();
pas.ForEach(name => DoSomething(name));
```